# Why I need to update targetSdk in Android projects?

Tags: android, performance, target-sdk

I can't found any useful info about why we need to update targetSdk in Android projects? I can simply update compileSdk to newer version, use new API, and have no any restriction, that can apply newer versions of Android.

Can I fill any performance issues if I don't update targetSdk?

Comment: You never *need* to update the `targetSdkVersion`. You may *want* to update the `targetSdkVersion`, in order to opt into newer system behaviors. For example, if your `targetSdkVersion` is below 24, then when the user tries using your app in multi-window mode on Android 7.0+ devices (e.g., split-screen), the user will see a pop-up bubble indicating that your app may not be compatible. Want to get rid of the bubble? Raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher.

Comment: I don't think the compileSdk can be higher than target without getting warnings

Comment: I would not consider this question a duplicate, as Kirill is asking exactly what I want to know: "why we need to update targetSdk?" @CommonsWare brought up at least one reason in his comment: getting rid of the split-screen incompatibility pop-up. What are the other repercussions, is there a list explaining those? What will change (besides the split-screen pop-up) when I update my app's `targetSdkVersion` fro 23 to 25?

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen: "What are the other repercussions, is there a list explaining those?" -- some are in the JavaDocs for the given release (e.g., `Build.VERSION_CODES.N`. Some are in the version release notes (e.g., [Android 8.0's](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#o-apps). And lots are undocumented, particularly the farther back you go in Android versions.